# Trying to use PHP to remove a line of HTML

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

Im trying to remove "Click" out of the code  after it has been used.  I need it to work in the beginning but after the class="details" is used, i need the code removed.  I figured I could use PHP for this?!?!?!

I know that I can use PHP to remove the HTML and I have been trying to use the preg_replace() function but its not working.

I cant color code the individual lines so i have have place large space about and below the HTML instance i need  and also below where the line occurs again, where I need the HTML to be removed.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 */
?>

<div class="cloud-computing-item">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h3> <?php print $company['name'] ?> </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item-subheader">    
      <div class="label">Services Offered:</div>
      <div class="data service-offerings">
      <?php 
        foreach($company['services_display'] as $service => $element){
          print $element;
        }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="item-body">
      <div class="overview">

        <div class="label">Cloud Providers:</div>
        <div class="data">
          <?php 
            foreach(array_slice($company['service_providers'], 0, 4) as $provider): ?>
            <div>
                <?php 
                print $provider;
                ?>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>






          <div style="color:#000099;font-weight:bold;">Click</div>





      </div>         
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <?php 







        $str = '<div style="color:#000099;font-weight:bold;">Click</div>';
            $result = preg_replace('(<style="color:#000099;font-weight:bold;">).*?(</div>)','$1$2',$str); 
        var_dump($result);
        ?>








           <?php foreach(array_slice($company['service_providers'], 4) as $provider): ?>
            <div>
                <?php 
                print $provider;
                ?>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php print theme('cloud_computing_item_details', array('company' => $company)); ?> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll want to use JavaScript or jQuery if you want to modify this without reloading the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant do it, php is server side language, after the page loads you can only do this with javascript, for example, you can add an attribute

```
"onclick='remove(); return true;'"
```

to the button and put the function:

```
<script>
    var remove=function(){
         $('#ID_OF_BUTTON').hide(500);
    } 
</script>
```

that will do the work

Comment: i dont mean to both but im not quite following you on how to use the coding.  i understand why and thats fine but how and where do i implement the code snip-its.

Comment: you can put the <script>.....</script> inside the <head> tags, and about the onclick,, you can do for example: <a href='www.something.com' onclick="remove(); return true;">Click</a>

Comment: would you guys vote on my most.  Im new here and Im trying to boost my reputation.  Please and Thank You.